# Qt: Alternatives to QTable for large datasets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm writing an application that displays the content of a database table. My application shall display an image associated with each tuple/row, among textual and numeric data.

The trouble is that I am dealing with huge data sets (up to 50k entries). The user will, of course, never see more than a few entries at once. But he should still be able to browse the data in a table-like view.

Regarding the visual appearance, QTable would just do the job. But, after reading blog posts about this, QTable seems to be pretty slowish for such tasks, which is understandable since, for let's say 50k entries, on the order of 50k widgets QObjects need to be created.

I though of using a QSlider as a replacement for the scrollbar of the table and a fixed layout. Whenever the slider is changed, the content of the gui-elements that make up the rows are adjusted.

However, is there any Widget and/or solution that provides the look and feel of a QTable but allows me to generate only those widgets that are actually displayed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "..on the order of 50k widgets QObjects need to be created." Why would they?  If you are only displaying an image and some text, the built in delegate can handle all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the paint-method of a corresponding delegate-class solves my problem. Thanks to cmannett85.